# How to rank headers with Duplicate Values in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I would like to rank the headers of the columns based on the value of each row.

Apparently I can use the LARGE function, to get top values.

But the problem here is that I have duplicate values. And when I try to use INDEX-MATCH, it will return the same header multiple times. It will not fetch the second header of duplicate score.

Refer my desired output:

[image: desired output]

I tried the solution mentioned at:

https://www.exceltip.com/lookup-formulas/vlookup-top-5-values-with-duplicate-values-using-index-match-in-excel.html

but I do not want to include randomize function.

Thanks!

Comment: Why is power with 4 for mary rank 1 and power with 1 for monica also rank 1?

Comment: i corrected the image. technically, it does not matter to me whether power is ranked as 1 or achievement. The focus i have is they should be higher in the rank.

Comment: How about adding `column()/100` to the numbers, so you can use the `large` approach without volatile functions. Currently dont have access to excel, so i can't test it.

Comment: It's too bad you don't have O365.  Then it would be simply `=SORTBY($B$1:$E$1,B2:E2,-1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, I added a fraction of the current column, so that the ranks are distinguishable by `MATCH`.

> ***Note** It's an array-formula which needs to be confirmed through <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd>*

```
=INDEX($B1:$E1,MATCH(LARGE(($B2:$E2+COLUMN($B$2:$E$2)/100),COLUMN(A1)),$B2:$E2+COLUMN($B$2:$E$2)/100,0))
```

Depending on the number of ranks, you can add smaller fractions, so that the ranks don't increment.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

About the question is to handle members of the same ranks. Two ways of handling indexes of the same values:

1. Place them in order in multiple cells.
2. Place them in order in one cell.
   Excel functions can handle certain of them, such as sorting in ascending or descending order. But others, such as getting the sequence number of a value before sorting and getting the sequence numbers. Using esProc is much easy.

> ```
>       A    
> 1     …(Data pasted from Excel)  
> 2     =A1.split@n("\t")  
> 3     =A2.(~.psort@z())  
> 4     =A3.(["Self     Direction","Power","Universalism","Achievement"](~))  
> 5     =A4.concat@n("\t")
> ```

For more explanation,see http://c.raqsoft.com/article/1610327593846

DISCLAIMER: This is about our tool esProc. It’s freemium.